# Kotlin functions with multiple default arguments: How to leave values out?

Tags: function, oop, kotlin

Let's say I've got the following function:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    demo("Test", 48)
}

fun demo(a: String = "a not given", b: Int = 0) {
    println("$a und $b")
}
```

**How would I invoke demo(), providing only the second parameter (the integer)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work try it

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    demo(b = 48)
}
```